# Ad hoc polymorphism on two typeclasses

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have two typeclass hierarchies that start with

```
class Animal a where ...
class Fruit f where ...
```

I'd like to define an ad hoc polymorphic function

```
eat :: (Animal a, Fruit f) => a -> f -> Int
```

that computes the amount of health an animal restores when it eats a fruit. By ad hoc, I mean I want to code specializations of `eat` for several combinations of type subclasses, for example

```
eat :: (Bird a, Nut f) => a -> f -> Int
eat b n = ...
```

When I call `eat x y`, I expect the compiler to execute the most specific known implementation of `eat` for the types of `x` and `y`. If no such typeclass combination is found, let it throw an exception.

Is this possible in Haskell ?

Comment: An exception at runtime or compile time?

Comment: I don't really mind, it shouldn't happen. I'll implement all the combinations I need.

Comment: Furthermore what is the most specific with two parameters: is `Animal a,Nut f` more specific than `Bird a, Fruit f`? The only thing that seems to make sense is a *Pareto front*, but that is only a partial ordering.

Comment: Specifying by animal first is fine.

Comment: If you really want to go down the type class approach, this sounds like you want `MultiParamTypeClasses`, then `class AnimalFruit a f`. Then you can have overlapping instances.

Comment: @Alec `class (Animal a, Fruit f) => AnimalFruit a f` lets me define instances for couples of types, like `instance AnimalFruit Int Int`. I need instances for couples of type subclasses instead.

Comment: I think you're misusing the class system. Just model `Animal` and `Food` as datatypes and define your `eat` function with pattern matching.